# Opening javascript popup window without address bar and title with height and width set in percentage according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, popup

I want to open popup window using javascript with no title and address bar and also want to set its height and width in percentage according to screen resolution.How can i achieve this. 
I did this code;

```
 function popitup(url) {

        LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - 800) / 2 : 0;
        TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - 700) / 2 : 0;
        var sheight = (screen.height) * 0.9;
        var swidth = (screen.width) * 0.8;          

        settings = 'height='+ sheight + ',width='+ swidth + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no, directories=no,titlebar=no,location=no,addressbar=no'

        newwindow = window.open(url, '', settings);
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
        return false;
    }
```

but still i can see address and title bar.Is this is relative versions and type of browser?.If so how can i achieve these settings in latest versions of browser like IE9,Chrome,Firefox and safari?

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons, this is not possible.

Check out
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/79625/How-to-hide-title-bar-in-Javascript-popup

You may use alternatives like modal dialogs which more appealing. Most JS libraries provide modal dialogs out of the box or by using plugins.

Comment: thanks for the reply.But i want to open popup on menu click and menu we are using is jquery menu not a asp menu. so how could i open popup on jquery menu click because jquery menu is in master page which already has lots of load so i don't want to add extra code load in it. also using above code my popup is still resizable but it should not be resizable as i changed resizable to "no" any specific reason for that?

Comment: With jQuery, it is only a matter of few lines of code. check -- 1) http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ 2) http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it supposed to be `menu = no` or `menubar = no`??

`settings = 'width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+top+', left='+left+',menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,toolbar=no'` worked fine for me.