# How to make link with hidden URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I was wondering whether it was possible to make a link with `<a>` tags that doesn't display its URL?

Put into other words, **I would like a piece of HTML that either hides or obfuscates the URL that it links to**.

I have found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522027/pop-up-window-with-hidden-url-address), but I'd prefer that the link would work in all browsers (not just chrome) and was not a popup. I already have access to jQuery, Bootstrap and PHP 5.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I feel this needs clarification. I do not want it to be visible in ANY way - i.e. this is a link that must NOT be shared, so I cannot simply use redirects and just hide the URL when it is hovered over - I do not want it visible in the source code either. Sorry for any inconvenience :(

Thanks,

ICT

Comment: So are you referring to removing the address bar or simply masking the current URL (accessed by the link) in the address bar?

Comment: @CallanHeard Well, I don't particularly want it to be visible in any way including looking at the source code. If it helps, I also have access to PHP 5.5 and PHP 5.4.

Comment: You can't hide an URL completly, it has to be somewhere.

Comment: @ICTman1076 Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @kappaismyname is right, the URL to the content must be accessed and present - but you can manipulate server access to mask the URI in the address bar

Comment: @CallanHeard How would you do this? Please explain in an answer, not a comment. Thanks :)

Comment: @ICTman1076 okay! I was just trying to clarify exactly what you wanted to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the link in a closure to hide it, then point the window there when the `<a>` is clicked, for example

```js
function hideLink(anchor) {
    var href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
    anchor.removeAttribute('href');
    anchor.className += ' pseudolink';
  
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = href;
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    hideLink(
        document.getElementById('my_link')
    );
});
```

```css
.pseudolink {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a id="my_link" href="http://google.com">Hover over me</a>
```

Comment: There had been already 2 answers with the same implementation, why had you wrote this ?

Comment: I have just tried this and I am afraid that it does not have the behaviour I want - the link is still visible via the source code, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @ICTman1076 You can't make the link not appear anywhere, even if you use AJAX to load encrypted data the client will need a decryption library and accessing it will be visible through their console (breakpoints)/network tab (when accessed). However, you can make links "spendable", this is how payment services work when they bounce you between merchant and payment provider, the link has an unique id in it which is only available for a few minutes and when accessed the server revokes the id. Depending on your use case, you could store such an id in the session data, e.g. `$_SESSION` in php

Comment: @PaulS. Interesting. So I could store the Session ID in a MySQL database along with an expiry time (i.e. 1 hour after the ID has been generated) and then make a link like `http://sorcerertech.pcriot.com/ranks/uprank.php?r=3&id=example` that checks the ID from the GET vars and sees if it is valid? Also, is it possible to make the MySQL entry self-destruct after a while without use of another PHP script?

Comment: First, I'm not sure if it's good to think of them as _Session IDs_, think of them as _an ID for Foo in the Session_. Second, using chrons etc you can remove old ones but that should be less frequent to clean up entries when a user did a dirty exit (closed browser without logging out etc). Instead when hit, look it up in the database, if found { store ref, delete from db, test ref for expired (e.g. time), if expired goto not found else YAY}, else (if not found or expired) NAY. This means the client is "cleaning up for themselves" as they use your site

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to completely hide the URL you are attempting to navigate to. The URL must be present in some form - such as the `'href'` attribute of the `<a>` - tag to tell the browser where to navigate to.

However, it is possible to mask the URL with access to your server settings. Using a `.htaccess` file it is possible to redirect from one entered URL to another, whilst maintaining the entered URL within the address bar of the browser. There are many sources online that explain how to do this.

Simply handling each link using some logic within a PHP file may be suitable to hide the link in the source. For example, you could send every link to `handler.php` and specify a value for which page to navigate to, ie `handler.php?page=1`.

`handler.php` would then contain something along the lines of:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['page'] == 1) header('Location: /where/you/want/to/go');
if ($_GET['page'] == 2) header('Location: /where/else/you/want/to/go');
?>
```

This way, the user will not know where the link actually goes and (using the `.htaccess` settings) unaware of the URL they have navigated to.

Comment: Interesting, but I do not believe this answers my question fully. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: @ICTman1076 ah sorry, I have just seen your update about the link not being shared/redirected

Comment: It does, but I would still have to put the redirecter link into the source code, meaning that users have the ability to simply copy/paste and share the redirecter link. P.s. it's OK :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an url minifier like this one : https://goo.gl/.

Comment: I don't think that would work, as they can just share the minified link. But thankyou anyway for the answer :)

Comment: OK, I thought your only need was to "hide" the real address at first view, not to protect from sharing. I don't think you can find any secure way to protect a link using Javascript. You should use a server side user and session management.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-link="some link here"></a>

$('a').on('click', () => {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-link');
});
```

User won't see the link while hovering it.

Comment: Will it also hide the link after it has been clicked or will I have to do something else to achieve that?

Comment: You can hide it easily, just add `$(this).hide()`.